# query with INNER JOIN

Tags: java, mysql, sql

The tables are created and have some data inserted I am trying to get the `route` from the `arrivaltimes` table with the aid of JOIN INNER but I am getting nothing back I have already tried to adjust the time to the current time  tin th arrivaltimes table but the result is always empty. I am not getting any error. Is something wrong with my query?

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stops
                        (stop_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
                         name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
                         lat double(10,6) NOT NULL, 
                        longi double(10,6)NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS arrivaltimes
  (arrivaltimes_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  weekday VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  route INT(11) NOT NULL, 
  arrivaltime time NOT NULL,
   stop_id INT, FOREIGN KEY fk_stop_id(stop_id) REFERENCES stops(stop_id) )


SELECT route from arrivaltimes INNER JOIN stops ON  arrivaltimes.stop_id=stops.stop_id where arrivaltime = now()
```

[image]

Comment: Could you also paste some sample data also?I think there is no data matching with `arrival time =now()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`arrivaltime` is having datatype `time` and its in the format `H:i:s`.

In the where clause you are using `now()` and it will be in the format `Y-m-d H:i:s`

You need to use `curtime` function for that.

```
mysql> select now();
+---------------------+
| now()               |
+---------------------+
| 2015-05-10 23:46:44 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select curtime();
+-----------+
| curtime() |
+-----------+
| 23:46:53  |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


where arrivaltime = curtime()
```

Comment: I have changed it but I am getting nothing back just empty result. Please see my question I have added a screenshoot for some data in the table

Comment: If you use `where arrivaltime = curtime()` meaning it has to have a record in the DB with the exact time when the query is getting executed. The probability is pretty low. You may use `where arrivaltime >= curtime()` to display data which are going to be arrived.

Comment: but if I put it like this I will get all arriavaltime greater equal the current time and not the particular one ?is there any way to ignore the seconds digits in the time?

Comment: Yes you may use `time_format` for that   `where time_format(arrivaltime,'%H:%i')= time_format(curtime(),'%H:%i')`; this will match only hour and minutes.

Answer (score 0):

your query is perfectly fine the problem is only with the time you provide as input.

The format of TIME data type is 'HH:MM:SS' so use time(now()) this will give you proper results.

mysql> select time(now());